# can we import specific version of botocore when implement Lambda in AWS?

Tags: amazon-web-services, lambda, windows-ce, botocore

when using cost explorer client in lambda function , 'ce' is not supported. but it may available in new version of botocore. so is it possible to import the new version of botocore in lambda python function ? if yes, how we can implement it. please provide some example

Answer (score 0):

AWS Lambda provides a way to  to use a version of Boto3 other than the one included by default, you can include it in your deployment package.

From [Creating a Deployment Package (Python)](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/lambda-python-how-to-create-deployment-package.html)

> AWS Lambda includes the AWS SDK for Python (Boto 3), so you don't need
>   to include it in your deployment package. However, if you want to use
>   a version of Boto3 other than the one included by default, you can
>   include it in your deployment package.

Comment: we must include boto3 at top of function, otherwise it show the error